# Jquery - live and on

Tags: jquery

To make it work for both static control and dynamic, we need to write the code using live() as below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="link">Link Static</a>
<button id="addmore" type="button">Add more</button> 
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#addmore').click(function() {
      $('body').append(' <a class="link">Link Dynamic</a>');
        return false; 
  }); 
   $("a.link").live('click', function() {
      alert('I am clicked');
   });
  });   
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, I see that live() is deprecated. I read that I need to use on() instead of live(). Can you please help how can I use on() for the above code?

Regards,
Niladri

Comment: Look at the api for on and http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the help of [event-delegation.](http://a.link)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#addmore').click(function() {
      $('body').append(' <a class="link">Link Dynamic</a>');
        return false; 
  }); 
   $(document).on('click', 'a.link', function() {
      alert('I am clicked');
   });
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

You should [*delegate*](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) it from a parent container like

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.link', function() {
    alert('I am clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#addmore').click(function() {
      $('body').append(' <a class="link">Link Dynamic</a>');
        return false; 
  }); 
   $(document).on('click', function() {
      alert('I am clicked');
   });
  });
```

REF:http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://jsfiddle.net/wf2kqLdj/2/

Comment: Sorry, seems not working. <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="link">Link Static</a>
<button id="addmore" type="button">Add more</button> 
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#addmore').click(function() {
      $('body').append(' <a class="link">Link Dynamic</a>');
        return false; 
  }); 
   $("a.link").on('click', function() {
      alert('I am clicked');
   });
  });  
</script>

</body>
</html>